# What is proper way for overriding part of components of a class?

Tags: python, oop, coding-style

I have a manager class which have dozens of 'worker' classes as members, most of worker classes are created in the constructor of manager class:

```
class Mgr(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
        self.b = B()
        self.c = C()
        ...
        self.z = Z()
    def execute(self):
        ...
```

Sometimes, I want to change one or more components, e.g. `self.b = B1()...` where B1 has same interfaces with B. I can do this way in caller side:

```
mgr = Mgr()
mgr.b = B1()
mgr.e = E1()
...
mgr.execute()
```

This is not good since every time I need to list the changes while calling the class.

Another option:

```
class Mgr(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A()
        self.b = B()
        self.c = C()
        ...
        self.z = Z()
        self.custom()
    def custom(self): pass

class Mgr1(Mgr):
    def custom(self):
        self.b = B1()
        self.e = E1()
        ...

class Mgr2(Mgr):
    def custom(self):
        self.b = B2()
        self.f = F1()
        ...
```

In this way, self.b is initialized as B() uselessly, which is not good in point of performance. And we cannot move custom function to top of constructor, since there are some order rule for creating A, B, C ...

What is the proper way for do it? In point of both OOP and performance. Any idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of organization, I'd say stick to having one `Mgr` class instead of having different variations.

If you're only wanting to change a few of the member classes for each instance of `Mgr`, I'd just pass in variables to the `Mgr` constructor to initialize them:

```py
class Mgr(object):
    def __init__(self, aBool = False, bBool = False, cBool = False, ..., zBool = False):
        self.a = A1() if aBool else A()
        self.b = B1() if bBool else B()
        self.c = B1() if cBool else C()
        ...
        self.z = Z1() if zBool else Z()
```

In that way, if you want to make a `Mgr` instance with all of the standard member classes except, say, `E` and `T`, you just call

```py
mgr = Mgr(eBool=True, tBool=True)
```

If you have more than two possible classes for each member (so more than just `A` and `A1`, you may also have some `A2`), then you could create a variation on this with something other than booleans passed in (as discussed in the comments on this answer), although the constructor might get uglier

This all still requires that you list out the changes to member classes you want to make when you create the `Mgr` instance, but at least you'll be able to condense it instead of calling one line of code for every changed member (and this also fixes the performance concern you had, as only either `A` or `A1` will be created)

Comment: Good idea! What about use class type instead of the Boolean? e.g.  mgr = Mgr(e=E1, t=T1) and 

class Mgr(object):
    def __init__(self, aCls = False, bCls = False, ...):
        self.a = aCls() if aCls else A()

Comment: That could work, though I'm not sure how python would like you changing `aCls` and such from `False` to some class definition... I'd say set the defaults as `aCls=A`, `bCls=B`, etc. Also remember that the constructor input parameter name has to be consistent (so if your constructor is `__init__(self, aCls...)` you can't call `Mgr(a=A1)`, you'd have to call `Mgr(aCls=A1)`.